# Snap.svg — consecutive transformations saving previous state

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to apply some transformations as reaction for user input to a group of elements and I'm pretty sure I do it wrong:

```
var SVG_WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
    SVG_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
    SVG_CENTER_X = Math.floor(SVG_WIDTH / 2),
    SVG_CENTER_Y = Math.floor(SVG_HEIGHT / 2),
    s = Snap(SVG_WIDTH, SVG_HEIGHT),

    obj = new myObj(SVG_CENTER_X, SVG_CENTER_Y);
    obj.drawIt();

function myObj( x, y ) {

    var that = this;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    this.is_scaled = false;
    this.angle = 0;

    this.g = s.group();

    this.drawIt = function() {
        var a = s.rect(this.x, this.y, 50, 50, 0, 0).attr({'fill':'#E82941'});
        a.appendTo(this.g);      
    };

    this.moveIt = function( dx, dy ) {

        var relative_dx = dx,
            relative_dy = dy;

        switch ( that.angle ) {
            case 0: {
                break;
            }
            case 90: {
                relative_dx = dy;
                relative_dy = -dx;
                break;
            }
            case 180: {
                relative_dx = -dx;
                relative_dy = -dy;
                break;
            }
            case 270: {
                relative_dx = -dy;
                relative_dy = dx;
                break;
            }
        } 

        var old_matrix = that.g.transform().localMatrix,
            new_matrix = old_matrix.translate(relative_dx, relative_dy),
            new_string = new_matrix.toTransformString();

            that.g.animate({'transform':new_string}, 200, mina.linear);   
   };

    this.rotateIt = function( angle ) {
        var old_matrix = that.g.transform().localMatrix,
            new_matrix = old_matrix.rotate(angle, that.x + 25, that.y + 25),
            new_string = new_matrix.toTransformString();

            that.g.animate({'transform':new_string}, 200, mina.linear);

            that.angle = Math.abs((that.angle + angle) % 360);
    };

    this.scaleIt = function() {

        var factor = 2;

        if (that.is_scaled) {
            factor = 0.5;
            that.is_scaled = false;
        } else {
            that.is_scaled = true;
        }

        var old_matrix = that.g.transform().localMatrix,
            new_matrix = old_matrix.scale(factor, factor, that.x + 25, that.y +25),
            new_string = new_matrix.toTransformString();

            that.g.animate({'transform':new_string}, 200, mina.linear);
    };
}

document.onkeypress = function ( e ) {

    switch ( e.charCode ) {
        case 97: { // A
            obj.moveIt(-50, 0);
            break;
        }
        case 100: { // D
            obj.moveIt(50, 0);
            break;
        }
        case 114: { // R
            obj.rotateIt(90);
            break;
        }
        case 115: { // S
            obj.moveIt(0, 50);
            break;
        }
        case 119: { // W
            obj.moveIt(0, -50);
            break;
        }
        case 122: { // Z
            obj.scaleIt(2);
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/GeMir/pen/GJMPQP?editors=001

WASD-Translations work just well.
Scaling works well too (zoom in/zoom out with object center as origin point).
Rotation works almost well, but only after some scalings (???).

The rectangle should rotate clockwise around its center and there should be no "jump" while rotating from 270 to 360 degrees (now it rotates to 0 degrees counterclockwise instead).

Comment: Personally I would probably forget about matrices, and control each of the translate/scale/rotate manually and apply via a built up transform string that does all three in one. You can always fiddle with matrices later when more comfortable with them.

Comment: I'm just wondering, if there is a «proper» way to do this kind of animations. Snap.svg seem to have some redundant functions.

Comment: I'm not aware of any redundant functions. There's just enough for a person to hang themselves ;). The problems typically arise from people trying to do something they don't understand (I don't mean that patronising), which is exactly why Snap and Raphael have transform strings, to simplify this. So my own take, is that the 'proper' Snap/Raphael way is to build your own transform strings, and not do things like matrix rotations.

Comment: You are probably right. Transformation strings are nice to deal with. You concatenate two or more of them and that's it. The only problem with strings is they are getting longer after each concatenation. To avoid this you need to split the old one and to construct the new one "manually". I was trying to avoid this using matrices (affine transformations are not that hard to understand).

Comment: You shouldn't need the old one, if you created it in the first place (ie you will know the 'total' rotation (its last rotation you can have stored eg rot 20, new rotation is +20, so you just set r40. Same with scale, so then you can do something like element.transform ('t'+newx+','+newy +'r'+newrot + s + newscale) type thing, just be wary of order you put them in. This way the string won't get longer than a string with one of each transform.